# After an update in Debian 11 packages I can't get X server working well, bluetooth error logs continuously go to stdout

Tags: debian, startup, bluetooth, dmesg

I'm getting some headaches recovering my Debian 11 system after an update of packages.

I have installed nvidia-driver in Lenovo X1 Carbon laptop and it was working.

After the updates, the welcome screen of Debian 11 is displayed and after a while the GUI is not loaded. A bluetooth error that goes in dmesg log goes to stdout, and I can't interact very well with the computer. Same goes into other interactive shells (`Ctrl + F2`, `Ctrl + F3` etc., although I can enter commands even the commands are interpolated with the error logs in stdout).

The error that is displayed continuously is

```
Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-22)
Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Read version failed (-22)
```

I tried to stop bluetooth service with `systemctl stop|kill bluetooth.service` but the service is restarted automatically.

So, I think first thing to do would be to really stop the bluetooth service.

I saw in other stackexchange item to use `rfkill` to stop the service but the program is not installed and I can't install it because the system has not access to internet because apparently the wifi interface and lan interface was not initialized yet.

The GUI is Gnome using X Server system.

I guess the description here is some generic, so fill free to ask me more details.